# Error while sharing local drive(volume) with docker for windows

Tags: docker

I am getting below error when I try to share local drive(volume) with docker for windows

```
docker run --rm -v c:/Users:/data alpine ls /data
C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: C: drive is not shared. Please shar
e it in Docker for Windows Settings.
See 'C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe run --help'.
```

I tried sharing the folder from the docker settings and provided my username and password but no luck and getting same error

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar issue with the error message "docker: Error response from daemon: Drive sharing failed for an unknown reason."

I opened the docker settings > Shared Drives > checked on C drive > Click Apply
and re-started docker to resolve the issue

[image: windows docker settings]

Answer (score 3):

I was facing a similar issue when starting containers with docker-compose. I got an error:

> A firewall is blocking file sharing between Windows and the containers.

Then I checked settings for Docker and under Shared Drives section I tried to check the checkbox for C: drive, but after hitting apply checkbox unchecked itself.

Then I copied the line `docker run --rm -v c:/Users:/data alpine ls /data` into Powershell, ran it and got the error:

> Drive sharing failed for an unknown reason.

But after this error, I decided to just try restarting Docker. After the restart, I tried to check the checkbox in the Shared Drives section once again and now it stayed checked and everything is working as it should.

I was using Docker Stable version.

Answer (score 2):

At the moment at Creators Update (1703) Samba shares are not working. There are a lot of tickets in official repo:

For example: [#662](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/662), [#669](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/639), [#756](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/756)

There is workaround described [here](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/530#issuecomment-293565549):

> The same started happening for me after installing the Win 10 Creators Update (Build 15063)
>
> Firewall rules are not the issue, those are correct
>      for some reason, after a reboot, I cannot access any local SMB shares on the DockerNAT interface (10.0.75.1)
>
> I am able to fix this temporarily by disabling and & re-enabling the"File and Printer Sharing for Microsoft Networks" component on the virtual "DockerNAT" network interface.
>      afterwards, I am able to browse \10.0.75.1
>      disable & re-enable the shared drive in Docker settings and it works - until next reboot

Answer (score 1):

I was dealing with similar issue during setup.
I couldn't share my directories with Docker because I was using my Azure AD login credentials. You need to create a local admin user. If the local admin doesn't appears right away you would need to reinstall Docker under local admin user.
I hope this helps someone struggling with similar issue.

Answer (score -1):

Like Shweta Gupta was saying, if you are using an AzureAD user, you'll need to create a local account on your machine, and use that to give Docker permissions to the drive.